# Creating database again and again on iphone 5 ios 7

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am creating a SQlite database on iphone 5 ios 7 using the following code in the viewDidLoad function of a view controller. Every time I viewDidLoad gets executed I am getting "// db mydb created". This happens  even though I am using the "create table if not exists" clause. Why does that happen? I want to have the database created only once and it seems it is somehow "invisible" and created again and again.

```
  // open database

    if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path!, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("error opening database")
    }

    if sqlite3_exec(db, "create table if not exists mydb (id integer primary key autoincrement, age text, hobby text, band text)", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {

            let errmsg = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(db))
            print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
    }else{
        print("// db mydb created")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "create table if not exists mydb (id integer primary key autoincrement, age text, hobby text, band text)", nil, nil, nil)
```

is not SQLITE_OK, then there is no error while executing the query-- it does not mean that db mydb is created again and again.